# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^n (1+ \frac{1}{a_r})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, infinite-product

> Evaluate the following infinite product:
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{r=1}^n (1+ \frac{1}{a_r}),\\
> a_1=1; \quad a_r=r(1+a_{r-1}).$$

I thought of two ways in which this might be evaluated: (1) By taking log and converting into a Riemann series which I saw isn't possible and (2) by converting into a polynomial equation of nth degree where coefficients become sums as per the theory of equations. Right now, I'm stuck, trying to figure out the way to proceed.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\left(1 + \frac{1}{a_r}\right) = \frac{(1 + a_r)}{a_r}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Gribouillis mentionned, it is generally a good reflex to try to fit the recurrence equation in the product (or the sum).
Here you have 
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{a_k}) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1+a_k}{a_k} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{a_{k+1}}{(k+1)a_k} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!a_1}$$
Let's see if we can find a limit for this. Note $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n!}$. With the recurrence relation, you get, by dividing by $n!$ :
$$b_n=\frac{a_n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}(1+a_{n-1}) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + b_{n-1}$$
So
$$b_n=b_1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$
and it is well known that $(b_n)$ has limit $e$.